# How do I fix NullReferenceExeption in my code?

Tags: c#, class, methods, null, nullreferenceexception

I have two methods in class Game.

```
public Player WhoWins(Player player)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < Board.Length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < Board.Length; col++)
            {
                //Horizontal Win
                if (Board[col, 0] == player.X_Or_O || Board[col, 1] == player.X_Or_O || Board[col, 2] == player.X_Or_O)
                {
                    return player;
                }
                //Vertical Win
                else if (Board[0, row] == player.X_Or_O || Board[1, row] == player.X_Or_O || Board[2, row] == player.X_Or_O)
                {
                    return player;
                }
                
                //Diagonal Win
                else if(Board[col, row] == player.X_Or_O || Board[col, row--] == player.X_Or_O)
                {
                    return player;
                }
                

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public bool PlayerMove(Player player, int x, int y)
    {
        if(x > 2 || y > 2)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("The idex is incorrect.");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
        }
        else
        {
            Board[x, y] = player.X_Or_O;

            **var win = WhoWins(player);**

            return win is not null;
        }
        return default;
    }
```

When I run the code, the bolded code(var win = WhoWins(player);) line stops it. The bug says:
'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: TicTacToe.Implementations.Game.PlayerMove(TicTacToe.Implementations.Player, int, int) in Game.cs'
What do I do know and how can I fix this?

I fixed it by checking if 'player' passed to 'PlayerMove' is null or not.

Comment: None of your `if` statements are true so your `player` is `null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I know but I can't even get to putting X on the board so that method can even start working. It shows up before I put the indexes of my choice.

Comment: Show us the full code please - where is `Board[]` defined? Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And what is the value of `player.X_Or_O`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary on the first move value of X_Or_O is X

Comment: Board is initialized in Board class

Comment: Step through the code, where is it exactly throwing a null reference? Which line?

Comment: 'var win = WhoWins(player);'
null reference is throwing here

Comment: Step in using the debugging, does it go inside?

Comment: If not, check `player` passed into `PlayerMove` is not `null`

Comment: No worries, make sure to double-check SO for duplicates next time! :)